# how to obtain a record of adjacent records

Tags: mongodb

Such as to obtain a post before an after a record time field created

Try to use the following statement to obtain articles

```
# Created is the time of the creation of the current article
# Before a
prev_post = db.Post.find ({'created': {'$ lt': created}}, sort = [('created', -1)], limit = 1)
# After a
next_post = db.Post.find ({'created': {'$ gt': created}}, sort = [('created', 1)], limit = 1)
```

The result turn to be discontinuous,sometimes skip several records.I don't know why,maybe I misunderstand the FIND?
Help please.

Comment: What do you mean, "the middle will skip a few good records"?

Comment: Can you include an example of your records and what ends up being skipped?  Also, do you have an index on the `created` field?

Comment: sorry ,I mean the result sometime skip several middle records,it doesn't the exactly neighbour record

Comment: Can you post an example of the documents? As mentioned in one of the answers, the problem could just be identical `created` dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may seem a strange behaviour indeed, but MongoDB does not guarantee you the order of stored records, unless you're querying an array (in which records are kept in the insertion order). I believe what MongoDB does - it reaches the first document that matches your query and returns it. 
Bottomline: if the logic requires neighbour records, use arrays.

Comment: I think perhaps you are conflating [sorting and natural order](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order).  The field to sort by should be indexed and be the last field in the query.  This does provide sorted results.  The possible exception would be ordering of results matching an identical sort value (eg. identical `created` time if you only have `created` as a sort value) .. but if that order was important you need to use a more appropriate sort key.

Comment: i do find the problem about time,there is some records have the same creating time.thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your *created*. the time type has a problem ,if the record time is same ,the system don't know which is the choosing one.you can use **_id** , have a try.